# Why does my .bashrc get read when I run noninteractive commands over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, shell

I've prepended each of my bash config files (`~/.bashrc`,`~/.bash_profile`,`~/.profile`) with `echo NAME_OF_FILE`, i.e. I get '.bashrc' when I source in `~/.bashrc`.

What baffles me is why I get and indication that ~/.bashrc gets included when I run a command over ssh. E.g., if I do:

```
ssh localhost echo hi
```

I get

```
.bashrc
hi
```

Why is getting `~/.bashrc` sourced in in this context? Shouldn't it NOT get sourced in since this should run an non-interactive bash session?

Indeed, `ssh localhost tty` gets me a 'not a tty' (preceded by '.bashrc' indicating that `~/.bashrc` gets sourced in nonetheless).

I've `grep`ped all my config files for commands sourcing in `~/.bashrc` explicitly, and there are none that explain it.

(I only have `tty -s && shopt -q login_shell && [[ -r ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc` in my `.bash_profile` so that I get '.bashrc' even in interactive login shells, but this doesn't explain the ssh issue—I can comment it out and I still get the same behavior with the above ssh examples)

How can I debug this?

Comment: Could it be your BASH_ENV variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `bash` man page:

```
Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input
connected to a a network  con‐nection,  as  if  by  the remote shell daemon,
usually rshd, or the secure shell daemon sshd.  If bash
determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes commands
from  ~/.bashrc,  if  that file  exists and is readable.
```

I.e. `~/.bashrc` will get run when you invoke it via `ssh`, regardless of whether you have a tty or not.

If you only want your `.bashrc` to run when you are interactive, try this at the top:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ "$-" != *i* ]] && return
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Comment: The manual page is a bit unclear, as most remote connection tools – rshd, telnetd, sshd – attach bash's stdin/stdout to a pseudoterminal, _not_ directly to the network socket (which would actually be impossible for sshd). Will check the source code later.

Comment: Both didn't work on CentOS 7.

Comment: @yildizabdullah you need to debug. Start by adding an echo or `set -x` at the top and see if your `.bashrc` is even being called. Then examine the values of those variables.

Comment: @Lqueryvg I added `echo` command at the top and it ran. That is, .bashrc was called.

Comment: Do a `set` and an `env` - try to work out what `$-` and `$PS1` are set to. (I'm starting to wonder if you are really in `bash`.). Type `bash` to get a sub-shell - so that you definitely know you are in a bash - and look at the values there.