# Why does rsync read .bashrc and not .profile?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync

`rsync` is a non-interactive program that logs into other machines. It shouldn't need the init file for an interactive shell session, and it should absolutely need the init file for a login shell. Or so I would think.

Yet `.bashrc` gets read and `.profile` does not (unless I make `.bashrc` itself read `.profile`). Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rsync` itself does *not* read your `~/.bashrc`. But it calls `ssh targethost rsync ...`, which will connect to an `sshd`, which in turn will start your shell (`bash`).

Why that `bash` now reads your `~/.bashrc` is explained in [Why does my .bashrc get read when I run noninteractive commands over ssh](https://superuser.com/questions/750747/why-does-my-bashrc-get-read-when-i-run-noninteractive-commands-over-ssh)

Comment: But can something be done about it?