# How to prevent .bashrc loading in when using ssh nc

Tags: bash, ssh

To log in to my work desktop, I have to first login to a internet-visible access server. Once I login to this server, I can `ssh` into my desktop using it's local hostname. To make this easy I have the following `ProxyCommand` setup in my `.ssh/config`:

```
Host access
Hostname access.blah.com
user myusername

Host desk
Hostname desktop_hostname
port 22
user myusername
ProxyCommand ssh -A access nc %h %p
```

My problem is that the home directory at work is synced between `access` and `desk` so they have to share the same `.bashrc` and other files. Unfortunately, the `.bashrc` I use on `desk` has some commands which fail on the `access` server, so I get ugly error messages when I type `ssh desk` on my local machine. Is there a way to change my `ProxyCommand` so that the `.bashrc` is not loaded on `access`?

Comment: Why not make those `.bashrc` commands that fail conditional? That is, to not run them on the server.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing, but I am worried that I could get into a whack-a-mole situation if they change the server's internal hostname.

Comment: This answer seems relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/750747/why-does-my-bashrc-get-read-when-i-run-noninteractive-commands-over-ssh?rq=1